# Have you guys ever tried Chinese beer? How would you rate it?

Tags: recommendations

I am a Food & Beverage industry analyst from China and I'd like to know if other overseas consumers know Chinese Beer and how do you guys rate it? Also, which brands do you know of (Tsingtao)? And any other opinions.
Personally I prefer German beer and don't like Chinese beer.

Comment: What does [tag:3.2-beer] mean?

Comment: @MonicaCellio The tag doesn't really apply to this question, but 3-2 beer is the term for reduced alcohol beer that is all some states allow to be sold by a supermarket or convenience store type retailer.  The name comes from the fact that these laws have typcially specified that only beer with an ABV of 3.2% or less may be sold by these licensees.

Comment: I updated the tag to reflect its meaning. It probably shouldn't be on this question now (unless chinese beers are all especially low gravity?)

Comment: You can find Tsingtao for sale in Italy, typically in Chinese, Japanese or Asian fusion restaurants. I think this is also due to compliancy to some western or EU standard of production (but this should be double checked)

Answer (score 2):

Most Chinese Beers are pale lagers or pilsners - bland, tasteless, and topped with glycerin as a stabilizer which gives people a pounding headache.

Many of my Chinese and foreigner friends would drink Carelsberg at the bar - a danish bland and tasteless beer.

When we had the money for it, everyone bought German or Belgian beer, 
even my friends in the far western provinces of Sichuan and Yunnan.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a Chinese beer, but in what I assume is Chinese style... I've enjoyed a couple lucky buddha's. Maybe it's similar in that it's rice based. It was very light and easy drinking.

I've heard of a Chinese beer called Snow and heard that it's extremely popular and well rated. I don't know how I can get any (probably can't) but would love to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I visited China last year and tried some of the local beers, including Tsingtao.  I was a bit surprised at the lack of variety (almost everything was a pilsner style larger) and that most beers were mid-strength at most.

None of them tasted bad, but nothing really stood out.